# Polymer Firebase image upload error

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymerfire, firebase-polymer

I have my firebase app config as so

```
<!-- NOT THE REAL VALUES --->
<firebase-app
  auth-domain="<auth domain>"
  database-url="https:DATABASE url"
  api-key="API KEY"
  storageBucket= "thebucket.appspot.com">
</firebase-app>
```

Each time I try an image upload I get the following error

`"Firebase Storage: No default bucket found. Did you set the 'storageBucket' property when initializing the app?"`

I dont understand as the storage Bucket property is there.

Comment: Hi, from your snippet, the issue is how you write `storageBucket` instead of `storage-bucket` as for other properties.

Comment: Your right.. I changed that and it works just fine. Thanks